# Term for JSON value at a particular location (properties?)

Tags: json

I would like to know what to call the JSON value associated with a particular name in an object. Is there such a term?

The [JSON spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf) (see also https://www.json.org/json-en.html) just mentions name-value pairs. JavaScript / ECMAScript calls them properties.

For example, in this JSON document

`{"animal": "frog", "weight": 100}`

if I wanted to refer to the value `frog` I could say "the `animal` property" if "property" were a definitive, unambiguous term. But if it isn't, then I may have to fall back on "the value associated with the name `animal`"

Comment: im not really understanding the question.. if you want to refer to a value for a specific key, you can just say 'value of key <name>' ?

Comment: `key` is not a term that appears anywhere in the JSON spec. Again, I know I can say "the value associated with the name `XYZ`". It would be easier to say "the `XYZ` property" but the term `property` is not part of the JSON spec.